# Visual Studio 2022 closes itself after short time on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2022, blue-screen-of-death

After experiencing a system bluescreen error while optimizing a Visual Studio project, the program stopped working correctly. The project involves connecting a device via USB and retrieving data from it using the device's library as a dll file within the solution. Visual Studio now closes itself without any error or unusual activity after the bluescreens occurred. Repairing or reinstalling Visual Studio did not resolve the issue.

Again, i am not asking for an explanation of the bluescreen error or how to prevent it which obviously related to my code or hardware, but for help in identifying what is causing Visual Studio to close and how to resolve it. **Also i should mention its crashes on opening other projects or a new project even sometimes before opening any project either.** The post includes the bluescreen error and a GIF depicting the issue:

My OS: Windows 10 Pro 22H2

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's your machine crashing, not Visual Studio. This could be bad RAM or an overheated CPU. `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` probably means bad RAM. Have you tried to search for that error code? Scan that QR?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You should run the Window Memory Diagnostic at the very least to check for hardware problems. Visual Studio uses a lot of RAM to analyze files in the background, so it's far more likely to end up using bad chips compared to other programs. A faulty *cooler fan* may also be at fault, if the CPU and RAM get too hot while VS works in the background.

Comment: I ran all diagnostics and could not find a faulty hardware. My essential issue here is not the bluescreen, debugging my program caused the bluescreen. The main issue is i can
't open the visual studio after this, its closing itself. How im a supposed to specify the issue when there is no error what so ever?

Comment: `involves connecting a device via USB and retrieving data from it using the device's library` that could be the problem too, if a bad hardware driver uses DMA to pass data to Windows. In that case, bad DMA would appear as a memory error. WinDBG will tell you this. You can't fix that through Windows though. Unfortunately, hardware manufacturers of such drivers are *notoriously* bad in software.

Comment: I had some very unpleasant experiences with FDDI USB/Serial drivers years ago for third party multiserial cards. The devices themselves didn't come straight from FDDI but that's where the bug was. So we had to first persuade the HW manufacturer that a problem really existed and we weren't idiots as they claimed (programmer error). In the end, we sent them the C++ example from Microsoft's (then MSDN's) doc page that would work with every serial device *except* their own. The fact we'd cancel an order for 600 devices with cause helped too

Comment: Does the device have a proper serial port driver? Have you tried using the virtual Serial port instead of the DLL?

Comment: Firstly thanks for your interest, device does not have serial port functionality. Besides, i am having the problem of visual studio shutting itself down even when that hardware is not plugged in or its drivers uninstalled. It is kind of broken or something is blocking it. My first guess was because of the visual studio caused the blue screen 2-3 times while working on the project, maybe windows automatically started to block visual studio afterwards in a defensive reflex or windows security started to think VS is a thread or something ?

Comment: Only the WinDBG analysis of the crash dump will tell you.

Comment: I have had the exact same problem. Unfortunately your inclusion of the BSOD has thrown off the commenters above, I would remove it from your question. I had a BSOD due to a known issue with my power supply. It just so happens I was running Visual Studio when one of the BSODs happened. Now I have the same symptoms as you: Visual Studio opens, and then randomly closes itself after 5-10s. The BSOD itself was unrelated to Visual Studio and I have separately resolved it, but there is this persistent side effect that means I can't use VS any more.